# How can I make the 'return character' for a text with several lines in an xml tag, which I parse then put in a UItableView?

Tags: iphone, xml, uitableview, return, line

I want to display in a UItableViewCell, text like

line1
line2

I get it from an xml tag like line1 line2

I've tried a lot of things, like:
`<br/> (also &lt;br&gt;),

\n which only displays "line1 \n line2",

<![CDATA[<br >]]> which only displays "line1 <br> line2".`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you setting the text like: `cell.textLabel.text = myText`?

I that case you are sending it to an UILabel, and UILabels can't have linebreaks.
What you can try is to create a custom cell with an UITextView and send your text there.

Example of a custom cell:
The tableview class:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"quickListViewCell";
    quickListViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"quickListViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[quickListViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (quickListViewCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    [[cell textFieldText] setText:@"Line 1 \n Line 2"];

    return cell;
}
```

quickListViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface appCountryCategoryViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UITextView *textFieldText;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textFieldText;

@end
```

quickListViewCell.m

```
#import "quickListViewCell.h"

@implementation quickListViewCell

@synthesize textFieldText;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Create a UITableViewCell in IB and set the identifier to "quickListViewCell".

Comment: Paul, thanks for the answer.
I agree with your example, but I am trying to get the text from an xml tag, and even if I write <tag>line1 \n line2</tag> in the xml, the text diplayed is only "line1 \n line2".

Comment: Have to tried writing it as an actual line break and using a textView.
e.g.
    <tag>line 1
    
    Line 2</tag>
/Paul

Comment: Ok thanks so much Paul, it does work.
So let me just summarize.
Your code is right, except some mistakes:
in quickListViewCell.h you wrote '@interface appCountryCategoryViewCell' but it is in fact '@interface QuickListViewCell'.

and I replaced the line '[[cell textFieldText] setText:@"Line 1 \n Line 2"];' by 
cell.textFieldText.text = [self nameForIndexPath:indexPath]

In my xml file I do a real line break between the two words <tag>line 1 Line 2</tag>.

In a xib called QuickListViewCell.xib, I added a QuickListViewCell. I added a UItextView inside which I linked with the quicklistviewcell.